# Wrapper/Controller Selecting Only Last Record from Query

Tags: apex, visualforce, soql, controller, wrapper-class

I've written a code, based on work by Jeff Douglas, to create a wrapper class/VF page that allows a user to search and select record(s), that then get passed into a Visual Workflow.

The search works correctly, and I don't have issues passing a value into my Visual Workflow.  The issue I have is that no matter which record I select, it always only passes the last record returned from the search query.

Can someone look at my controller/wrapper and help me understand why it keeps only sending the final record?

Below is what I believe is the relevant part of the Controller

```
public class RibbonClauseSearchControllerv2 {



// fired when the search button is clicked
public PageReference search() {
    String strRibbonId = '';

    if (searchResults == null) {
        searchResults = new List<RibbonClauseWrapper>(); // init the list if it is null
    } else {
        searchResults.clear(); // clear out the current results if they exist
    }
    // Note: you could have achieved the same results as above by just using:
    // searchResults = new List<RibbonClauseWrapper>();

    // dynamic soql for fun
    String qry = 'Select rc.Name, rc.Id, rc.Text__c, rc.Clause_Name__c, rc.Template_Name__c, rc.Additional_NST_Details__c From RibbonClause__c rc Where rc.Name LIKE \'%'+searchtext+'%\' Order By rc.Name';
    // may need to modify for governor limits??
    for(RibbonClause__c rc : Database.query(qry)) {
        // create a new wrapper by passing it the category in the constructor
        RibbonClauseWrapper rcw = new RibbonClauseWrapper(rc);
        // add the wrapper to the results
        searchResults.add(rcw);
        system.debug('-->searchResults Anil2'+searchResults);
    }
    return null;
}   

public PageReference next() {
    List<RibbonClause__c> ribbonclauseList = new List<RibbonClause__c>();
    String strId = '';

    PageReference myVFPage = new PageReference('/apex/RibbonClause_Results'); 
    // clear out the currently selected 
    selectedRibbonClauses.clear();
    ribbonclauseList.clear();
    system.debug('****Anil1***before***'+ribbonclauseList);
    // add the selected ribbonclause to a new List
    for (RibbonClauseWrapper rcw : searchResults) {
    strId = '';
    System.debug('RCW Anil >>'+rcw);
        if (rcw.checked)
            ribbonclauseList.add(rcw.rc);
            strId= rcw.rc.Id;
            System.debug('****strId***...' + strId);
            system.debug('****Anil1******'+ribbonclauseList);
    }
System.debug('****strId***.after..' + strId);
    strRibbonId = strId;


   return myVFPage;

}       


// fired when the back button is clicked
public PageReference back() {
    return Page.RibbonClause_Search;
}       

// fired when no clause available button is clicked
public PageReference noclause() {
    return Page.clauseKeyPage;
}

public PageReference getCloseWindow() {
    return new PageReference('/apex/RibbonClause_closeflow');
}

public class ribbonClauseWrapper {

public Boolean checked{get;set;}
public RibbonClause__c rc{get;set;}

public RibbonClauseWrapper(){
    rc = new RibbonClause__c();
    checked = false;
}

public RibbonClauseWrapper(RibbonClause__c rc2){
    rc = rc2;
    checked = false;
}    
}
```

Below is the visualforce page:

```
<apex:page controller="RibbonClauseSearchControllerv2" sidebar="false" showheader="false" >  
    <apex:slds />
    <apex:form >
        <apex:pageBlock rendered="True" >

            <apex:pageBlockButtons >
                <apex:commandButton action="{!back}" value="Back"/>
            </apex:pageBlockButtons>
            <apex:pageMessages />

            <apex:pageBlockSection title="You Selected" columns="1" collapsible="true">
                <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!selectedRibbonClauses}" var="rc2" style="width:100%">
                    <apex:column value="{!rc2.rc.Name}" headerValue="Name" Style="width:100px"/>
                    <apex:column value="{!rc2.rc.Text__c}" headerValue="Language" Style="width:600px"/>
                    <apex:column value="{!rc2.rc.Id}" headerValue="Id" Style="width:1px" />


                </apex:pageBlockTable>
            </apex:pageBlockSection>           

        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
    <flow:interview name="Approval_Record_Creation" buttonLocation="top" finishLocation="{!CloseWindow}" buttonStyle="color:#050; background-color:#fed; border:1px solid;">    

<!-- <apex:param name="vRibbonClauseId" value="a0hg0000001sMroAAE" />-->
   <apex:param name="vRibbonClauseId" value="{!strRibbonId}" />
  <!--  <apex:param name="vRibbonClauseId" value="selectedRibbonClauses" />-->
    <apex:param name="v_UserId" value="{!$User.Id}"/>
    <apex:param name="vMId" value="{!$CurrentPage.parameters.Id}"/>
    </flow:interview>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: can you post only relevant code supporting your question

Comment: I don't see where you set the check = true,  add a value to the selected list, or how you pass it on to a flow or "send" it anywhere. Based on your code `strRibbonId` will only ever be a single value, is that what you are trying to pass?

Comment: I will update the post to show the relevant code.  It is passed on a VF page, using <param> in <flow:Interview>.  Yes, the `strRibbonId` is all I am trying to pass now.   I left the VF page out to keep the post from being too long...  But i'll remove some of the other post and add in the VF page.

Comment: @Eric The portion with the check=true, which is where I believe the issue may be, is in the public `PageReference next()` method in the controller.

Comment: @Clink - I just don't see it. I don't see a `check=true` or a `checked=true` in the `next` method you posted I am guessing it is set by the VF page. Also, are they allowed to select multiple records or just one

Answer (score 2):

Your code:

```
    for (RibbonClauseWrapper rcw : searchResults) {
    strId = '';
    System.debug('RCW Anil >>'+rcw);
        if (rcw.checked)
            ribbonclauseList.add(rcw.rc);
            strId= rcw.rc.Id;
            System.debug('****strId***...' + strId);
            system.debug('****Anil1******'+ribbonclauseList);
    }
System.debug('****strId***.after..' + strId);
    strRibbonId = strId;
```

is actually this:

```
for (RibbonClauseWrapper rcw : searchResults) {
    strId = '';
    if (rcw.checked) {
        ribbonclauseList.add(rcw.rc);
    }
    strId= rcw.rc.Id;
}
strRibbonId = strId;
```

and so appears to be an example of this problem [Single statement if block - braces or no?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/16528/single-statement-if-block-braces-or-no).

To fix, selecting the first checked one would be:

```
for (RibbonClauseWrapper rcw : searchResults) {
    if (rcw.checked) {
        ribbonclauseList.add(rcw.rc);
        strId= rcw.rc.Id;
        break;
    }
}
strRibbonId = strId;
```

and removing the `break;` would select the last checked one.

(In the code you posted `ribbonclauseList` served no purpose and so should be removed.)